# Will carbon fork make a huge difference when commuting?

Tags: commuter, cyclocross, hybrid-bike

I am considering a hybrid commuter bike, in particular I like Specialized Sirrus Elite Disc. This model however does not sport a carbon fiber fork. Only the more expensive model does, which I do not have budget for.

Another candidate would be Trek Crossrip, which does have carbon fork. Should I make getting carbon fork a priority, will it make a real difference on my ~13 km commute? I sometimes do ride over surfaces like this, that's why I'm concerned:

[image]

Comment: When you talk about carbon forks or "not-carbon" forks, you should appreciate that "not-carbon" forks will be made of steel. And in terms of smoothing your ride, steel can be every bit as good as carbon. Where carbon wins - and this is why you see it on higher-end bikes - is in terms of weight.

Comment: Ok, so basically you're saying I should not concern myself too much with carbon/non-carbon in a bike, which will primarily be used for commuting? I'm not saying I wouldn't like to take it on the read once in a while, but for the most part 500g here and there won't make too much of a difference. Especially since my requirement is for the bike to have disc brakes...

Comment: For a fast/lightweight bike, "not-carbon" forks are usually made of aluminium, not steel. Checking the specifications for that Sirrus, the fork is "Cr-Mo steerer, aluminum crown/lowers".

Comment: My other non related question would then be, are those 32 mm tires on the CrossRip maybe too much for commuting? I suppose I won't be doing too much riding on any gravel roads, that's what my XC is for. Maybe I could getaway with a purebred road bike with 28 mm tires -- provided I can fit them.

Comment: @vclaw - I hadn't looked at the bike's spec, but nevertheless the argument remains the same. For what the OP requires I see no point in getting stressed about whether the forks are carbon or not. In terms of offering suspension, other materials will serve as well.

Comment: @VoY - I'd recommend asking that as a separate question but bear in mind that having wide tyres is also a pretty effective way of smoothing your ride.

Comment: Frame Geometry has as much an impact on ride comfort as material. You cannot state "Its got a carbon fork so it will be better"

Comment: @mattnz But he is asking about upgrading a specific bike to carbon level/version.

Comment: @Blam - Hes states the carbon option is too expensive and is looking at another bike (the Trek) with carbon fork.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not much difference in ride from carbon to Cr-Mo.  Over 13km not much of a factor. The carbon is going to be lighter, more expensive, and less durable.  Same bike on a budget I would go Cr-Mo.  You list two different styles of bikes and a purebred road bike in a comment.  Pick the style of bike first.  I don't think purebred road bike is the right bike for that picture.  I personally think drop bars are more efficient and comfortable for paved commuting. And on a budget used might be more cost effective.